# Pointer being freed was not allocated problem with ALL objects!

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm working (at least trying...) on a **Cocoa** application, which uses several custom **Cocoa frameworks** and one of these frameworks is a mix of **C++** and **Objective C++** (mostly **C++**) code... The problem is that each memory deallocation inside this framework gives me the **Pointer being freed was not allocated** error, even in the following trivial case:

```
class testClass
{
public:
    testClass() { }
    virtual ~testClass() { }
};

void test()
{
    testClass *p = new testClass();
    delete p;
    // malloc: *** error for object 0x2800510: pointer being freed was not allocated
    //*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    p = NULL;
}
```

**malloc_error_break** tells me that the **object's destructor is being called**, however every next allocation increases the object's address, so the memory is really not being freed... **Please tell me, WHY?!**

I have to use **Mac OS X 10.6.0**, **XCode 3.2.1**, **Apple GCC 4.2.1**.

Comment: _next allocation increases the object's address_ What does this mean ?

Comment: if I make 3 allocations/deallocations in a row, I'll get the folllowing errors: error for object 0x2800510, error for object 0x2800520, error for object 0x2800530...

Comment: The fact that the next allocation(s) take place at a different address does not in itself imply that the memory is not freed.

Comment: I agree, Pascal, but it's plausible

Comment: Oh man, I must be loosing it! I added an allocation / dealloacation block in the application's entry point, and all malloc errors have vanished... What the hell?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a chance, that one of these custom frameworks redefines `new` and/or `delete`? Try to add this replacements to your test program and look if a) the test program builds without complaining about multiple definitions of new and/or delete and b) it runs and shows a delete for every new?

```
 // not a real replacement, for testing purposes only
void * operator new (size_t sz) 
{
 printf("my new\n");
 return malloc(sz);
}
void operator  delete (void*ptr) 
{
 printf("my delete\n");
 free(ptr);
}
void operator  delete[] (void*ptr) 
{
 printf("my delete[]\n");
 free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Wait, how am I supposed to do it? Unfortunately GCC doesn't allow new/delete operators overloading, it will give the 'Redefinition of' errors...

Comment: Of course you can define your own new/delete in C++ with GCC. Unless of course, something else provided a new/delete overload - which is what I wanted to find out. Could you add the errors gcc gives you to your post? Are they happening during compile or link time?

Comment: Thanks, Luther! It appears you were right - the new and delete operators are already overloaded and malloc errors are probably caused by using new/delete operators before the initialization of a framework, which overloads them. Man...